# make textbox not to inherit any css

Tags: css

I want to create a textbox to make a loginform. But there is alot of css on it that i don't want to use. Im also using bootstrap so there is a lot of standard css classes and stuff that the textbox inherits. How do i make it not inherit any other classes or can i make it to be reset so that it doesn't have any css classes except the ones i tell i to?!

[image]

One of the problems i have is that the textarea looks like it is sunk into the background i rather want it so look flat.

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS

```
input[type="text"]{border:none; box-shadow:none; width:auto}
```

you can change any of these properties at will, or apply to all input elements by deleting the [text] part

Comment: I assume that you meant `input[type="text"]`.